# Pycharm longer output

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have a pandas df and the output is:

```
8        IF YOU HAVE ANY PROBLEMS WITH TODAY'S FIL...
```

how do I make it longer, I tried

```
desired_width = 1000
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
```

but it still gives the same output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use :

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', desired_width)
```

here is the [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html) to all the options available.